# How to suppress the reset of the subsection counter

Tags: sectioning, numbering, article

I am using the class report right now, and would like to use `\subsection` as a running counter throughout the entire chapter, without reseting it in a new `\section`.

Tried to research this myself, but since google is flooded with `how to reset counter`, I couldn't find what I was searching for.

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{subsection}{section}`... and this perhaps one of the most asked questions here on TeX.SE ;-)

Comment: This doesn't help at all, actually it counteracts what I want
I need the section and the chapter counter before, but I only want to suppress the reset of the subsection counter.
This solutions deletes said counter.

Comment: Then use `\counterwithout*{subsection}{section}` ;-) Reading the manual can help ;-)

Comment: Well stating this is a duplicate and then stating that reading the manual to actually understand both problems are interlinked did help to. What means I would have to read the manual of a package maybe not helping at all, to understand it would help. Instead of asking a community that wants to help and wants to share knowledge. Said behaviour counteracts the share of knowledge and leads to elitist behaviour. Like stating that reading the manual helps.

Comment: Where in your initial post was the line that you want to keep the numbering displayed as is? Even if you edit and 'change' the question afterwards, it is still a duplicate of some other question, I am pretty sure. The suggestion to read the manual is also a pretty natural thing to do, in my opinion the manual would be the first thing to check after some suggestion has been done.

Comment: I actually changed it back to the first version, since your comment answered the initial question.

And since I have a bunch of work, I can't possibly read every manual that might could help, especially if the outcome seems to miss-interpret the initial question. That's why I am thankful for every helpful and constructive comment.